# How to find the user current path?

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7

I'm on linux, I wrote a python script that is located in lets say `/home/python/main.py`. Every time I run it, it asks for a path using `raw_input`. I run it from a different place every time.

say I run it from `/home/test` like this `python /home/python/main.py` from terminal.

How can I give it the path I'm currently in, if possible. I don't want to hardcode paths. So I want to give it the path from which I'm using the terminal. I don't want to do `pwd` and copy paths,

I'm wondering if there's something like `~` which always points to home directory. Something similar which points to the users current directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `os.getcwd` - returns current working directory. Requires `import os`.

Also its slightly unclear, what exactly do you want. You dont really need current working directory in python - every relative path in python will be interpreter as if starting in current directory. So simply use relative paths (in linux those are ones NOT starting with /) - this will work as long as you dont change current directory (which is a bad habbit anyway).